# I can't install anything in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center

It says this:

```
(installArchives() failed: dpkg: error processing package coreutils (--configure):
 package coreutils is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
Error in function:)
```

After that I shutted it off and rebooted. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try to run this in a terminal: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt-get install -f`; then retry

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to remove lock:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Then clean:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get --purge autoclean
```

Now try to update:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --force-all --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```